# How to share supervisor's child pid to another child in Erlang/OTP

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

In my Erlang/OTP application I have a `one_for_all` supervisor (**sup**) with several childs. One of the children (**child1** with `gen_server` behaviour) should be able to send messages to the other one (**child2** with `supervisor` behaviour). Of course, I can register it but clogging up the global scope with excess names doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Thereby the only way of making such interaction possible is to provide **child1** with the pid of **child2**. No sooner said than done. There is `supervisor:wich_children/1` call with appropriate functionality. Just passing **sup**'s pid as the argument to **chidl1**, calling `which_children` in the `child1:init`, and... getting a deadlock. **sup** is waiting **child1** to start, **child1** is waiting **sup** for children descriptions:

```
init(SupPid) ->
    Descriptions = supervisor:which_children(SupPid),
    ... .
```

This can be fixed by the following kludge:

```
init(SupPid) ->
    gen_server:cast(self(), initialize),
    ... .

handle_cast(initialize, State) ->
    Descriptions = supervisor:which_children(SupPid),
    ...  % Generating new state containing desired pid
    {noreply, NewState}.
```

However, I wasn't satisfied by this solution.

The question is: What is the most conventional way of interacting between supervision tree members according to OTP design principles?

Comment: Could you explain why your solution doesn't satisfy you?

Comment: If you intend to create an application, it can run only once per VM, so in the case you describe, I don't think that using locally registered process is a bad solution.

Comment: @Pascal, yes, I intend. But such registration cause not only name clashes between instances of the "application", but also increasing probability of name clashes with other process. Nevertheless, it looks like I should consider this solution.

Comment: @evnu, this solution doesn't look very natural and clear. I created the new message specially for using it once at the initialization phase. This message is sent by process to itself... Occam turns in his grave (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor).

Comment: You could also make the supervisor send a message to the newly created child. Just move call to `gen_server:cast/2` from `init` to the supervisor. Concerning the message just for initialization: Think of it as a state machine. The external input makes it change from state `inactive` to `active`.

Comment: @evnu, Can I do it after each restart of the children by supervisor in some way?

Comment: Hm, I didn't think of that. To do it on restart, only the child's `init` is a good place for that message, so you'd end up with your solution again.

Comment: to avoid name clashes I usually choose the module name as process name, if I have no module name clash, there is low chance that I have it for process one.

Answer (score 5):

Surely you cannot ask the supervisor about its children while it has not yet started them all :)

Registering (locally, using erlang:register()) is not such a bad idea, actually. Moreover, if dealing with raw pid in child1 you should manually setup monitoring on child2 pid in order to be able to react on possible crashes etc, but being registered you just ask it straight away by name.

Without registering, you could defer notifying children until supervisor:start_link is called:

```
start_link() ->
    R=supervisor:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, []),

    %% Here supervisor is started so you can notify its children
    R.
```

Comment: Possible crashes are not the problem, because `one_for_all` supervisor will restart all its children if one is crashed. So manual monitoring isn't really necessary. Of course, not if we notify children just once when supervisor started.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on your business logic but if it makes sense to you to be worried about clogging up the global scope, my suggestion is that you consider the supervision strategy that you are using.

What I have seen in such cases when the two peer processes need to be associated in such a way, is that an extra controller process is created to manage this association and a simple_one_for_one sup is used to spawn one of the two peer processes (the gen_server most likely). This technique, again may be used when using process registration is  a concern, such as when you will have many instances of those gen_servers running the same code.

The technique would basically consist on using a simple_one_for_one supervisor to spawn your gen_server. What happens basically is that when started (a simple_one_for_one sup) does not spawn any child processes immediately but only when you explicitly call `supervisor:start_child(Sup, List)`.

Then your child2 initialization logic (or even your business logic at some point) could spawn the gen_server via the `supervisor:start_child(Sup, List)` and be fed with the child2 Pid so that they can communicate painlessly.

The extra controller process keeps a dict of the relationship between your gen_server, identified by some uniqueness but avoiding the global space clogging  since this is just a local to the controller. Then you may be able to ask your controller to allocate or deallocate this relationship at any point on your logic.

The supervision tree would therefore look something like:

[image: supervision tree]

You can read code using this implementation on the [tinymq](https://github.com/evanmiller/tinymq) project on github

If you have never used a simple_one_for_one supervisor before, the child specification may be a bit tricky, bear in mind that you would pass the child2's pid to your gen_server via the list on the `supervisor:start_child(Sup, List)` which gets appended to the Args one, that you specify on the child spec.

[simple_one_for_one supervisors](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#id72282)

My two cents!